# constant update RSSI number swift

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth, rssi

I'm new to corebluetooth. My aim is to keep reading RSSI number of the connected device. I can read the RSSI number once, however I have no idea how to initialise to read the RSSI number constantly. Can somebody suggest? Followings are my code so far

```
func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!, advertisementData: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, RSSI: NSNumber!) {
    self.connectingPeripheral = peripheral
    centralManager.stopScan()
    self.centralManager.connectPeripheral(peripheral, options: nil)
    ConnectingLabel.hidden = false
    println(peripheral)
    println( RSSI )
}
```

Comment: Do you have a code sample showing how you read RSSI *now*?

Comment: Hi, yup i have update my question with lines of codes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once you are connected to the peripheral you can call `peripheral.readRSSI()` periodically. This will result in a callback to the `peripheralDidUpdateRSSI` `CBPeripheralDelegate` method. At this point you can access the peripheral's RSSI property.

Strangely, both the `peripheralDidUpdateRSSI` delegate method and `RSSI` property are flagged as deprecated in the documentation, but no alternative is provided and no warnings are given by the compiler when you use this method and property, so I suspect it is a documentation bug.

Comment: hi, i have a question that how can i get the value by calling this function?

Comment: Some time after you call that function you will get a call to the CBPeripheralDelegate function, `peripheralDidUpdateRSSI` - You need to set your object as the peripheral's delegate and implement this function.

Comment: Yup i have done the implementation and delegate as well. i used func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didReadRSSI RSSI: NSNumber!, error: NSError!) instead, but i would like to ask how can i keep firing the readRSSI function whenever RSSI number change?

Comment: oh, i can solve it, simply call the peripheral.readRSSI() function under the didReadRSSI function method. Thank bro, have a great one

Comment: Yes, or you can use an NSTimer to call the function; this gives a little more control over the frequency at which you will request updates

Comment: @Paulw11, is there any other way to get the updated RSSI on every change in signal without using NSTimer?

Comment: Not really. If you aren't connected and your app is running in the foreground you can use the duplicate discovery option in your scan and get the rssi in the `didDiscover` callback

Comment: Thanks. So can I get continue RSSI changes updates after connecting to device?

Comment: If you poll it via a timer